# 2 dimentional array initialisation and usage

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, initialization, declaration

I am writing a java program that uses a lot of matrix calculation and during certain calculations I use multiple temporary "storage" matrices before further calculation.

I have declared the temporary matrices in the class variables as such

`private double[][] intermediateMatrixA;
 private double[][] intermediateMatrixB;
 private double[][] intermediateMatrixC;
 private double[][] intermediateMatrixD;`

However, I've never initialise the matrices in the constructor or methods in the form of `intermediateMatrix = new double[][]`.
Instead i am doing this for each temporary matrix `intermediateMatrix = [the product of a matrix calculation]`

My question : Is the method I'm using safe baring in mind the temp arrays will be reused in other calculations? Each time I declare one of my temp matrices should equal another array it will equal the exact dimension and values of that matrix?

Thanks in advance 
Regards 
Mike

Comment: It's unclear to me how this works - if you could post more code I could be more certain. But this is what I'll tell you: You cannot get something from nothing. If you are multiplying matrices, you need to create a new double[][] somewhere to store the new values.

Comment: And I HIGHLY recommend you go and google for the JAMA matrix package - matrix math is hard enough as it is without writing your own library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is 'safe' in the way that your variable from above, will point to the result of your method or calculation, and the rows and columns will be preserved.

```
private double[][] intermediateMatrixA = new double[3][4];
//etc etc
intermediateMatrixA =new double[5][6];
```

Is perfectly fine, as long as it is always a `double[][]`; The logic of keeping track of the rows and columns is up to you though.

You can assign types of `double[][]` to other types of `double[][]`, but not `double[]` to `double[][]`.

If you intend to used them again and again, I would suggest setting them to null before you assign them, just in case.